# Tag synonym: google-datastore and gae-datastore?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Can someone add [google-datastore](/questions/tagged/google-datastore) as a synonym of [gae-datastore](/questions/tagged/gae-datastore)? They are exactly the same thing.

(I tried to do the reverse, but I was forbidden from doing so as gae-datastore has more than 1.25x the number of tagged questions.)

Comment: not a duplicate - "If you want to tackle one, please make a separate meta question and link it here."

Comment: Check, dupe vote retracted.

Comment: Note for future viewers - the official tag is [google-cloud-datastore], not [gae-datastore]. Also adding the tag [google-app-engine] can be done if you need to denote it is used via App Engine.